# Save Scilab's ode output to table

Tags: ode, scilab

I have a system of ODEs solved in Scilab via

```
x=ode(x0,t0,t,syst);
```

I would like write the output to csv/tsv file with every row corresponding to each time step and columns representing variables in x.

Comment: Can you validate the answer below if it fixes your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

```
csvwrite(x',"file.csv")
```

should be enough, and if you need the time values on first column use

```
csvwrite([t(:) x'],"file.csv")
```

The `'` allows to transpose the output of `ode()` where each column gives the variables at a given time step (you need the transpose here). `t(:)` ensures that time values are given as a column vector to allow horizontal concatenation with `x'`. If you need a particular column separator, decimal mark and/or precision see the help page of csvwrite (`help csvwrite` on the command line).